# What is the IE version of webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I have a script which works with:

```
...
webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
webdriver.Capabilities.firefox();
webdriver.Capabilities.safari();
...
```

but fails on any concatenation of `Internet Explorer` I've tried. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: `webdriver.Capabilities.internet_explorer()` didn't work?

Comment: I tried with webdriver.Capabilities.internet_explorer(), webdriver.Capabilities.internetExplorer(),webdriver.Capabilities.ie(). Not working

Answer (score 1):

It looks like (at least as of v2.40), ie() is the correct function name.

```
/**
 * @return {!webdriver.Capabilities} A basic set of capabilities for
 *     Internet Explorer.
 */
webdriver.Capabilities.ie = function() {
  return new webdriver.Capabilities().
      set(webdriver.Capability.BROWSER_NAME,
          webdriver.Browser.INTERNET_EXPLORER).
      set(webdriver.Capability.PLATFORM, 'WINDOWS');
};
```

Maybe there's something else preventing ie() from working when you try and use that function? Let us know more details, maybe provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
var ie = new WebDriver.Builder().withCapabilities(
    WebDriver.Capabilities.ie()
).build();
```